# dynamically define key name for which the value needs to be identified

Tags: c#, list, keyvaluepair

I have a keyvalue pair list some thing like this

```
 List<Subscriptions> subs = new List<Subscriptions>();
subs.Add(new Subscriptions() { Id = 1, Name = "ABC" });
            subs.Add(new Subscriptions() { Id = 1, Name = "DEF" });
```

I can search against one key (ID or Name) but what I want to achieve is that user define which key they want to search against **ID or Name**

right now i am using this approach to filter the list based on Name Value

```
 var filtered = subs.Where(sub => sub.Name.IndexOf(SearchString.Text,StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >=0);
```

**sub.Name** is defined statically here, I want the user to choose what they want their search to be based on

for example if we have **abc:Name** program search for abc under Name key and if we have **1:Id** then it search for 1 in ID.
This is just an example , in real scenario i can have multiple fields in my list.
I hope I am able to make myself clear.

Answer (score 2):

Why you don't apply the `Where` by an simple `if else` or `switch`

```
// keyword : abc:Name or  1:Id
var value = keyword.Split(':')[0];
var key = keyword.Split(':')[1];

if(key == "Name")
{
    var filterred = subs.Where(sub => sub.Name == value);
}
else if(key == "Id")
    var filterred = subs.Where(sub => sub.id == int.Parse(value));
}
```

Comment: this is a good approach if I only have two fields , but what if I have more than 2 field to search against ? it will be too many code lines then. I want it to be dynamic

Comment: With a switch, you can add many fields that you want. I think you don't have other solution simpler

Answer (score 2):

**Fast answer:**

```
string name = "";
int? id = null;

List<Subscriptions> subs = new List<Subscriptions>();

var query = subs.AsQueryable();

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
    query = query.Where(p => p.Name == name);

if (id.HasValue)
    query = query.Where(p => p.id == id.Value);

var result = query.ToArray();
```

**Detailed answer:** you can read about [expression tree](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/expression-trees/) and [`IQueryable` interface](http://rosoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.iqueryable?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Basically you can avoid to cast your list to `IQueryable` if you not use something like Entity Frmework or OData. But if you need to convert you LINQ expression to something more complex - you should use `IQueryable`, or build your own expression tree.